How to use react-leaflet Marker component with leaflet-maptilersdk, to make the popups interactive?
In a Next.js project, I am currently using leaflet-maptilersdk to display a vector tiles map.
I used this example.
I initialize my map like this :
map.current = new L.Map(mapContainer.current, {
            center: L.latLng(center.lat, center.lng),
            zoom: zoom,
            zoomControl: false
        });

        // Create a MapTiler Layer inside Leaflet
        const mtLayer = new MaptilerLayer({
            apiKey: "myApiKey",
        }).addTo(map.current);

<div className={styles.mapWrap}>
   <div ref={mapContainer} className={styles.map}></div>
</div>

And then, I add markers on the map using L.marker.addTo(map), and I append popups with marker.bindpopup
data.forEach(point => {
            const marker = L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon }).addTo(map.current);
            marker.bindPopup(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomReactPopup />))
        });

My problem is, using this solution, I can't create popups with inner react components as children, for example clickable buttons.
I tried rendering my component and then append it to the popup as plain HTML
  const CustomReactPopup = () => {
    return (
      <div style={{ fontSize: "24px", color: "black" }}>
        <p>A pretty React Popup</p>
        <button onClick={() => { console.log("test") }}>Test</button>
      </div>
    );
  };

marker.bindPopup(ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<CustomReactPopup />))

But button the button isn't clickable.
I saw the react-leaflet documentation, and that I could use the <Marker> component, but only inside a <MapContainer> context.
So is it possible to create <Marker> components in my context ?
